# React Native How to prevent keyboard from dismissing on text submit?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I want to be able to hit the enter button on the keyboard, keep focus on the `TextInput`, and keep the keyboard open. How can this be done?

The answers about `ScrollView` implmentation refer to touching a button outside of the `TextInput` as opposed to actually hitting the return key on the keyboard.

Comment: Could you provide some code

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The way to do this on a `TextInput` is to set `blurOnSubmit={false}` and then use `onSubmitEditing` as the submit handler instead of `onEndEditing`.

```
  onTextChange(input) {
    this.setState({ value: input })
  }

  submitValue() {
    // Do things with the value 
    ...
    // Then reset it so the TextInput can be reused
    this.setState({ value: '' })
  }

    <TextInput
  blurOnSubmit={false}
  style={styles.inputBox}
  onChangeText={input => this.onTextChange(input)}
  onSubmitEditing={() => this.submitValue(this.state.value)}
  value={this.state.value}
   />
```

On pressing of the return key `this.setState({ value: '' })` to clear the text from the `TextInput`.

Comment: Could you give some explanations what `blurOnSubmit` is doing? How *blur* is related to not hiding keyboard?
It work, but now looks like some hack / magic.

Comment: focus and blur effects are opposite to each other, so when input is focused i.e. when user clicks on it the keyboard opens up. When user clicks done or clicks away the TextInput is blurred resulting in keyboard dismiss event. By preventing blur on submit we are forcing to keep the focus on TextInput, and that's why keyboard is not dismissed or closed.